# What is the 0-60mph time of an aircraft carrier catapult?

Tags: fighter, jet, aircraft-physics, aircraft-carrier

Tesla's new Roadster is giving a 0-60mph time of 1.9 seconds. Truly ludicrous acceleration.

I was wondering how a fighter jet released from a steam catapult compares.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_catapult an American carrier type Kitty Hawk has a catapult capable of accelerating a mass of 35000 kg to 139 knots (71,51 m/s), and the system's stroke is 76 m.
From the terminal speed and the stroke, a simple calculation gives a mean acceleration of 33,64 m/s/s. Hence, and assuming the acceleration constant along the stroke, the time needed to reach 60 mph = 26,81 m/s is
t=v/a => t=26,81/33.64 => t=0,796 seconds...

Comment: Ha.  Beat that, Elon.

Comment: Thanks - I take it back. The Tesla's quick but the catapult is ludicrous.

Comment: In some fighters, there are special handrests that the pilots need to grab during a carrier launch, because there is a danger that they knock themselves out if they don't have their hands holding on to something. Teslas have a steering wheel you can hold on to, but I'm pretty sure that one is used for actual steering. So, there's still some way to go. (I'm also pretty sure that the new electromagnetic catapults on the Gerald Ford class are even more ludicrous.)

Comment: Nice answer. From my calcs, that's a lazy acceleration of 1.45g for the car, compared to 3.43g for the aircraft, almost 2.4 times as much.

Comment: That's pretty incredible acceleration. On top of that, I believe they are uniquely tuned for each takeoff, in order to cater to different aircraft types and armament configurations. Fingers crossed Elon (or someone else) can find a practical use for fighter jet level acceleration to the joe schmoes of the world.

Comment: " The Tesla's quick but the catapult is ludicrous. "  And the Tesla won't even fly at the end of the launch.  More of a plummet into the sea ...

Comment: @CrossRoads - Falling, with style...

Comment: @Jorg, the cat shot isn’t that dramatic to where you’d get knocked out. Very similar to the roller coasters that linearly accelerate the cars rather then drag them up a hill. There is a cat grip that the pilot grabs along with the Power Control Lever to avoid pulling the power to idle during a shot.